# Alternativa para CSS3 Shapes compatível

Tags: css3, front-end

Estou com problemas para montar uma parte do layout de um projeto que estou trabalhando no momento.
O texto deve ficar contido dentro de um poligono. Para melhro visualização do que estou tentando explicar:

[image: texto contido]

O site tem que ser compatível com todos os navegadores, desde o IE7/IE8.
Existe alguma forma compatível de fazer isso?

Comment: Tente este recurso aqui - em teoria compatível com IE6+: http://www.csstextwrap.com

Comment: Essa solução não me parece a mais correta.
Estou aceitando soluções com canvas...

Comment: Canvas foi parcialmente implementado a partir do IE8; não há solução baseada em canvas para IE7. (Existem workarounds, mas a performance é deficiente.) Fonte: http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas

Comment: Certo, mas no caso de o browser não suportar Canvas, eu posso remove-lo deixando assim apenas o título e o link para o qual ele vai direcionar. Existe algum plugin que faça essa modificação no texto automaticamente. Seria muito melhor se eu pudesse apenas das os pontos do polígono.